3D Comic book about a Wizard who uses geometric shapes to cast spells
I probably read this comic book in the 80's but I have no idea when it was published. I don't think it was DC or Marvel, but not 100% sure. I remember at least part if not all of it being in Anaglyph 3D (the cardboard glasses with one eye red, the other eye cyan).
The plot revolved around a wizard who created magical spells by combining these crystalline geometric objects of a limited variety  that were somehow the spell components (it's possible that the different shapes/colors of the objects represented elements or some similar theme). If I remember correctly they were stored in a kind of subspace that he could summon before him, but this detail might not be accurate. He ends up facing an enemy that he had previously defeated and he uses up all of his spell components to prove to his adversary that he was actually dead and had been reanimated just for the sake of vengeance. Upon realizing this the enemy disappears. The wizard than makes some comment about having to rebuild his supply of magic.
